# How to change srand() at runtime

Tags: c++, runtime, srand, random-seed

I'm using `srand(`) with a fixed seed and I need to run tests with a set of different seeds like 100, 200, 300, ..., 1000 all in one execution. Is this possible? The thing is `srand()` is defined at the beginning of main, so I don't know how to control the seed with a variable.

Comment: srand() can be used wherever you want.  If you want a particular test to have a particular seed, then call srand(seed) before the test.

Comment: just put the code in a for loop, and call srand aht the beginning of f each  iteration

Comment: Are you asking how to specifically modify the variable in the seed so that it will output 100, 200... 1000? Or any other sequence?

Comment: no, I need only modify the value of the seed...thanks for all the answers

Answer (score 3):

You can use srand(time(NULL)), and include the time.h header. It initializes srand() with the current system time. Hope it helps. !!

Comment: That is not very useful for unit tests. When running unit tests you want rand() to return the same set of numbers so you use srand() with a constant value at the beginning of each test to make sure you get consistent results.

Answer (score 0):

If a unit test tests code that uses rand() then you should call `srand(<const>)` as part of the setup of the test.

This way the test behaves in the same way weather it is part of a suite are run independently.

Answer (score 0):

For every different seed value used in a call to srand, the pseudo-random number generator can be expected to generate a different succession of results in the subsequent calls to rand.
Two different initializations with the same seed, instructs the pseudo-random generator to generate the same succession of results for the subsequent calls to rand in both cases.

This might illustrate:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  printf ("First number: %d\n", rand() % 100);
  srand ( time(NULL) );

  printf ("Random number: %d\n", rand() % 100);
  srand ( 1 );

  printf ("Again the first number: %d\n", rand() %100);
  srand ( time(NULL) );

  printf ("Random number: %d\n", rand() % 100);

  printf ("Random number: %d\n", rand() % 100);

  printf ("Random number: %d\n", rand() % 100);

  printf ("Random number: %d\n", rand() % 100);

  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
First number: 41
Random number: 76
Again the first number: 41
Random number: 76
Random number: 14
Random number: 74
Random number: 41
Press any key to continue
```